# Rails downloads empty file when doing a POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, post

I have a POST method that adds a like to a model post

```
  def like
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.likes += 1
    post.save
  end
```

I'm a using a link_to to call it.

```
<%= link_to "like", like_path(post), method: "POST" %>
```

But whenever I click, an empty file downloads.

[image: Click here to see the image]

Comment: How's your route defined in `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: Would you share the corresponding route in `config/routes.rb` ?

Comment: I'd recommend to use something like `Post.increment_counter(:likes, params[:id])`. If you use the approach you described, the counter might not have the right data, why ?; suppose you make a request to like a post, then I do the same, for some reason each request loads the `post` having `post.likes = 2`, then your request is processed & updates the post which will set `likes = 3`, then mine does the same and since the `post` instance also had `likes = 2` at the time it was loaded, my request will set `likes = 3` in the DB as well. You'll end up with `-1` like than the ones you would expect.

Comment: `patch "/like/:id", to: "posts#like", as: "like"`

Comment: The first argument is the HTTP verb you're gonna use for the route, try changing it to post.

Comment: Changed it to POST and it still downloads an empty file

Comment: Is there a corresponding view for the `like` action that can be rendered? Or what do you expect Rails to respond? Would a redirect be more appropriate?

Comment: That code, with the post route, works.

Comment: When using redirect_to the file isn't downloaded, but I want the user to keep on the same page. The code works, the post gets a like when "like" is clicked, the only issue is the empty file being downloaded when clicking "like"

Comment: Would you share the request headers?

Comment: You have a request, you cant simply ignore the res unless you are using websockets, a modern frontend stack or remote true. Simply add redirect_to @post or :back after the save call and your vote will be posted and as a response your user will be redirected to the page the vote was submitted. Also, see below answer from another user.

Comment: Show the log of the server when you do that request.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of a request, you need to make a decision what page to render or where to redirect the user to. In your example, it seems like you want to redirect the user back to that post page they came from:

```
def like
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.increment(:likes)
  post.save

  redirect_back(fallback_location: post)
end
```

I suggest reading about [`redirect_back`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back).